# Exponential Integral \frac{u}{k}e^{jvk}

Tags: integration

Can we say this integral is equals to zero?
\begin{align}
p_1=\int_{-k_{\max}}^{k_{\max}}\frac{u}{k}(e^{jv_1k}-e^{jv_2k} )dk
\end{align}
where $j=\sqrt{-1}$, $u, v$ and $k_{\max}$ are both constant number.
I know the old indefinite version of $p_1$ is cannot be integrated, but this definite $p_1$ can be integrated. But not sure if $p_1==0$.

I Learned from the answers to old quesiton that
\begin{align}
p_2=\int_{-k_{\max}}^{k_{\max}}\frac{u}{k}e^{jvk}dk = 2juSi(k_{\max}),
\end{align}
by principle value, so the integral $p_2$ is not depended on $v$, then can we say $p_1==0$? I just want to make sure if the result of $p_2$ not relay on $v$ is true or not.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

This function is not integrable in elementary terms and sense. Yet there is a special function that comes in handy with these types of integral, and it's the [Exponential Integral function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_integral) (Ei).

That is, in general:

$$\int \frac{e^{j a k }}{k}\ \text{d}k = \text{Ei}(j a k)$$

In your case there is a problem though, for the limits of integration are between $-k_{max}$ and $k_{max}$ which means that the point $0$ is crossed along the path, making the integral non convergent.

You might try a Cauchy Principal Value, but I don't really think it will solve something...

**EXTRA**

If we assume that both $u $ and $v$ are not just constants but REAL constants, then we could manipulate the result a bit via Principal Value, which would guarantee some solution in terms of another related special function.

So:

$$u \lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \left(\int_{-k_{\text{max}}}^{-\epsilon} + \int_{\epsilon}^{k_{\text{max}}}\right) \frac{e^{j v k}}{k}\ \text{d}k$$

Will give us

$$u\left(Ei(-k_{\text{max}}v) - Ei(k_{\text{max}}v)\right)$$

Since $\lim_{\epsilon \to 0} Ei(-\epsilon) - Ei(\epsilon) \to 0$

Now we can express that result in terms of the [Sine Integral](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/SineIntegral.html) function (Si). Consider this a parallelism between the relation between the complex exponential and the sine function.

Eventually

$$Ei(-k_{\text{max}}v) - Ei(k_{\text{max}}v) = 2 j Si(k_{\text{max}}v)$$

Whence

$$\text{PV} \int_{-k_{\text{max}}}^{k_{\text{max}}} \frac{u}{k} e^{j v k}\ \text{d}k = 2uj \text{Si}(k_{\text{max}}v)$$

Comment: what if we consider that $k\in[-k_{max},0),(0,k_{max}]$?

Comment: Going to add few edits.

Comment: thank you for your analysis, actually, v is a REAL constant,

Comment: And may I ask what the $PV$ mean in your last line? and seems the result $2ujSi(k_{\max})$ is not dependent on $v$, so I can say $\int_{-k_{\max}}^{k_{\max}} \frac{1}{k} (e^{jv_1k}-e^{jv_2k})dk=0$? where $k_{\max}$ is real and positive; $v$ is real but could be both positive and negative and zero.

Comment: @CharlieNie I beg your pardon, I forgot the $v$ constant. Going to edit!

Comment: @CharlieNie PV means "Principal Value". You can learn about, searching for "Cauchy principal value". It's a method to assign a value to certain integrals, for example if you integrate $1/x$ from $-3$ to $3$ it does not converge for it crosses $0$. But its PV is zero (justified also by being it an odd function). The same doesn't apply, to say, if you integrate $1/x^2$ in the same range, so there must be attention!

Comment: Thank you for your answers and explainations! Really appreciate it!

Comment: @CharlieNie You're welcome. Glad I could help!